# Django all striptags apart from <p>

Tags: django, django-templates

In the template language is it possible to strip all tags but keeps the ones with the paragraphs(`<p>`)?

Example:

Given:

```
<p>In this lesson, you will learn how to apply....</p>
<br>
<img src="http://example.com/photos/b/8/d/0/60312.jpeg" style="max-height : 700px ; max-width : 700px ; margin : 5px">
<p>After attending this workshop you will always be the star!</p>
<ul><li> Test </li></ul>
```

Final Output:

```
<p> In this lesson, you will learn how to apply....</p>
<p>After attending this workshop you will always be the star!</p> Test
```

Comment: Could you provide an example input and example output?

Comment: @alecxe sure. Updated

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain why do you want to do it in django templates? (describe use case please)

Comment: I have a database with one object in each row having `html`, the one that I use above. These objects have content such as images and lists that I don't need in my final display, so I want to strip them. However I want to keep the paragraphs in order to have a clean appearance and not be "a one sentence thing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in Python with [bleach's `clean` method](https://github.com/jsocol/bleach), which you could then wrap in a template filter if you need it in your template. Simple usage:

```
import bleach

text = bleach.clean(text, tags=['p',], strip=True)
```

Your custom filter would look something like this:

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter
import bleach

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
@stringfilter
def bleached(value):
    return bleach.clean(value, tags=['p',], strip=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using `templatefilter` and `beautifulsoup`.
Install BeautifulSoup. then create a Folder `templatetags` inside any app `folder`. you need to add an empty `__init__.py` inside `templatetags` folder.

inside the `templatetags` folder create a file `parse.py`

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from django import template    
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def parse_p(html):
    return ''.join(BeautifulSoup(html).find('p')
```

#### in template.html

```
{% load parse %}

{{ myhtmls|parse_p }}
```

where `myhtmls` is

```
<p>In this lesson, you will learn how to apply....</p>
<br>
<img src="http://example.com/photos/b/8/d/0/60312.jpeg" style="max-height : 700px ; max-width : 700px ; margin : 5px">
<p>After attending this workshop you will always be the star!</p>
<ul><li> Test </li></ul>
```

Comment: Are you sure that'll give him the OP the output they want? I think that'll lose the "Test" bit in the list.

Comment: @DominicRodger i think if he need to do it in templates then this is a good option. I don't know why he sticks to templates. he has better use the `beautifulsoup` in `views` rather than `templatetags`. if he gave us full code, may be we can help him better. :)

Comment: my point is that your code doesn't give the output he wants. It's perfectly valid to use filters for this (after all, what he wants isn't a million miles from `striptags`, which is shipped with Django).